# How to get last N documents from collection in mongo?

Tags: c#, mongodb, find, mongodb-.net-driver

In `C#` how can I get `last N` inserted documents from the collection in `mongo`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I made solution

```
SortByBuilder sbb = new SortByBuilder();
sbb.Descending("_id");
var allDocs = collection.FindAllAs<BsonDocument>().SetSortOrder(sbb).SetLimit(N);
```

Answer (score 1):

The general pattern is using

```
docs = collection.find().sort({'_id' : -1}.limit(N)
```

By sorting on _id you will take into account that the standard object id is only increasing over time (unless implemented otherwise). Otherwise you need to sort on some timestamp field that you add/maintain within your code and application.

Comment: I know it is in mongo. But I need it in C#

Comment: What have you tried? using find() and sort() is documented in every documentation for every driver...read up

Comment: I found solution, I didn't know about SetSortOrder